Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x^2-xy+y^2}{y-x}$.
This problem gives me a lot of trouble. I am asked to solve the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x^2-xy+y^2}{y-x}.$$Note that this is non-linear, non-homogeneous, non-exact, and inseparable for variables $x$ and $y$.
This is a problem on my final exam. I gave attempts to test for known form of equations and substitutions but they yield nothing.

Maple can't solve it either. Everybody can make an error, so 1) Are you sure you copied the equation exactly? 2) And was solving the equation the subject of the question?

@MasB Yes I have a copy of my exam. I am sure the equation is copied exactly. The question is to solve for a general solution. I doubt then they made a typo.

Ask your teacher if the problem is wrong
